# How to prove if the following is a dual vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I have just started learning dual spaces and in my current understanding, I know that dual vectors are vectors that maps vectors onto scalars. However, how do I prove if a vector is a dual vector? For example, let V be the space of real polynomials of degree < 3.

Are the following dual vectors?

1. p → p(3) p'(4)
2. p → ev<sub>5</sub> ((x+1)p(x))

If dual vectors maps vectors onto scalars, does this mean that both 1 and 2 are considered dual vectors? If not, how do I prove that they are not dual vectors?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Comment: A dual vector cannot be any map from vectors to scalars, it must also be linear. This is the non-trivial condition one has to check here.

Comment: The dual vector space consists of linear forms, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space).

Answer (score 1):

Dual vectors are linear maps from the "original" to the field of scalars $\mathbb F$, let's take the first map, $F(p)=p(3)p'(4)$ with $p \in \mathbb F_2[x]$ .

Well, $F$ it's a map from $\mathbb F_2[x] $ to $\mathbb F$, so what is left to check is the linearity, therefore we have to check that:

1. $\forall p,q \in F_2[x]$ , $F(p+q)=F(p)+F(q)$
2. $\forall p \in F_2[x]$ and $\forall a\in \mathbb F$ , $F(ap)=aF(p)$

Can you continue from here?